# Server Error in '/' Application when I am running the simple method in WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

[when i add the method test in u-r-l it says error in server application]
[this is what's inside my W.C.F service and I am trying to view method test][3]

```
    public string test()
    {
        // Add your operation implementation here
        return "test...";
    }
```

Below it the error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdFt9.png

Comment: Please don't insert a picture of your code into the question. Insert the code as text so it's easier to help you

Comment: https://localhost:44305/Service/Service1.svc/test (when i added test in the url it says error in server application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to directly access your WCF operation in the browser, you can refer to the below configuration.
**Service Contract.**

```
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string GetData(int value);
}
```

**Service.svc**

```
public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
```

**Web Configuration**, just replace the System.servicemodel section.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Result.
[image]
For more details about how to create a basic WCF Web HTTP service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-wcf-web-http-service
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.